# The commanding Riley

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a form of money.
> My suffix has electrical charge.
> My infix is your abbreviation.
> Altogether I command.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Form of money?

> CENT

Has electrical charge?

> ION

Your abbreviation?

> UR

What am I?

> CENTURION

Comment: Thats the correct answer. :)